# Discord.js auto-ban user if they use a certain command

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm attempting to make a simple `$ping` command but if a user uses said command, they'll automatically be banned from the server (a small little funny)

Here's the code for the functioning `$ping` but I don't know how to have the ${user} that uses it auto-banned from the bot. (Will have sufficient perms obviously)

I'll be removing the whole embed: section down basically, as I don't need any text or actual command running. Just the auto-ban, only thing ran will be a `description: ${user} was banned`

```
    exports.exec = async (Cuckbot, message) => {
  try {
    let responseMessage = await message.channel.send({
      embed: {
        color: Cuckbot.colors.BLUE,
        description: 'PINGing...'
      }
    });
    await responseMessage.edit({
      embed: {
        color: Cuckbot.colors.BLUE,
        title: `${Cuckbot.user.username} PING Statistics`,
        fields: [
          {
            name: 'Response Time',
            value: `${responseMessage.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms`,
            inline: true
          },
          {
            name: 'WebSocket PING',
            value: `${Cuckbot.ping}ms`,
            inline: true
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
  catch (e) {
    Cuckbot.log.error(e);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`member.ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) is a function you can use to ban a **member**.
Example from Documentation:

```
// Ban a guild member
member.ban("Banned because used ping")
  .then(() => console.log(`Banned ${member.displayName}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```